# Why is this a receiver type mismatch when it seems to match what I see in the Gradle docs?

Tags: gradle, signing, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I'm converting a build from Buildr to Gradle.

So far I have the following build script:

```kotlin
repositories {
    jcenter()
}

allprojects {
    version = "0.8.1-SNAPSHOT"
    group = "org.trypticon.hex"
}

subprojects {
    apply(plugin = "java-library")
    apply(plugin = "maven-publish")
    apply(plugin = "signing")

    configure<JavaPluginExtension> {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        withJavadocJar()
        withSourcesJar()
    }

    dependencies {
        "testImplementation"("junit:junit:4.13")
    }

    configure<PublishingExtension> {
        repositories {
            maven {
                url = uri(if (version.toString().contains("SNAPSHOT")) {
                    "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots"
                } else {
                    "https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2"
                })
                credentials {
                    username = System.getenv("DEPLOY_USER")
                    password = System.getenv("DEPLOY_PASS")
                }
            }
        }
        publications {
            register<MavenPublication>("mavenJava") {
                pom {
                    // omitting a bunch of metadata unrelatted to the issue
                }
            }
        }
    }

    configure<SigningExtension> {
        sign(publishing.publications["mavenJava"])
    }
}
```

When I try to build, I get this:

```
build.gradle.kts:124:14: Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch: 
public val PluginDependenciesSpec.publishing: PluginDependencySpec defined in org.gradle.kotlin.dsl
```

IntelliJ says that the types match and shows no error.

I started with code from the Gradle docs which said to use this:

```kotlin
    signing {
        sign(publishing.publications["mavenJava"])
    }
```

But that fails when inside a `subprojects` block.

Using:

- Gradle 6.8
- Java 11.0.3

**Further investigation:**

I tried splitting the lines out to see exactly which bit the issue was on.

```kotlin
        configure<SigningExtension> {
            val e: PublishingExtension = publishing
            val p: Publication = e.publications["mavenJava"]
            sign(p)
        }
```

The error points directly at `publishing` on the first line. Hovering over it in IDEA, it helpfully tells me that `Project.publishing` is a `PublishingExtension`, so the call shows no error. Now the question is, why is it fine when inspecting the file, but fails at runtime? I thought this was exactly the kind of thing switching to Kotlin was going to stop. :(

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem, which I fixed by writing the following code:

```
configure<SigningExtension> {
    val pubExt = checkNotNull(extensions.findByType(PublishingExtension::class.java))
    val publication = pubExt.publications["your_publication"]

    sign(publication)
}
```

In your case, `your_publication` should be replaced with `mavenJava`.